# How can I calculate percentage changes of multiple variables and time points at once?

Tags: r, dplyr, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

Using `dplyr` syntax, I am looking for an "elegant" way to `mutate` new variables to a given data frame containing percentage changes across different time points.

As an example, consider the following `data.frame` containing variables (`var.a`, `var.b`, `var.c`) taken at different time points (`A`, `B`).

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(replicate(6,sample(1:100,50,rep=TRUE)))
names(df) <- c("A.var.a", "A.var.b", "A.var.c", 
               "B.var.a", "B.var.b", "B.var.c")
```

How could I calculate percentage changes from `A` to `B` of each respective variable, and `mutate` them to the data frame `df` ? I am looking for a `dplyr` or any other "smart" solution that I could implement in a bigger data frame containing more time points and variables, avoiding typing one by one new variable containing the desired output.

Comment: I think I know the solution but show me please a few top rows from output data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [tidy](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html) it up and then aggregate each pair. Something like

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% tibble::rowid_to_column() %>% 
  gather(key, value, -rowid) %>% 
  separate(key, c("time", "var"), extra = "merge") %>% # split "A.var.a" into "A" & "var.a"
  arrange(rowid, var, time) %>%
  group_by(rowid, var) %>%
  summarise(diff = diff(value)/value[1]*100) %>%
  spread(var, diff) 
# # A tibble: 50 x 4
# # Groups:   rowid [50]
#    rowid      var.a     var.b     var.c
#  * <int>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#  1     1 193.103448 380.00000 -56.66667
#  2     2 -36.708861 115.55556 -32.35294
#  3     3  -4.878049 -23.75000  22.44898
#  4     4 -71.910112 300.00000 -71.87500
#  5     5 -87.368421 -28.07018  10.20408
#  6     6 680.000000 323.80952 -12.22222
#  7     7   9.433962 184.61538 -81.52174
#  8     8 -75.555556 -61.84211 -32.78689
#  9     9 -19.642857 -80.00000  14.28571
# 10    10 -52.173913 -52.63158 480.00000
# # ... with 40 more rows
```

?

To add the columns to your original data, you could add `%>% ungroup() %>% select(-rowid) %>% rename_all(~paste0("perc_", .x)) %>% bind_cols(df)` to the above lines.

Or try a rowwise approach in the veins of

```
 f <- function(x) {
  as.list(diff(x, lag=3)/x[1:3]*100)
}
df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  do(data.frame(perc = f(unlist(.)))
  ) %>% 
  bind_cols(df)
# Source: local data frame [50 x 9]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
# # A tibble: 50 x 9
#    perc.B.var.a perc.B.var.b perc.B.var.c A.var.a A.var.b A.var.c B.var.a B.var.b B.var.c
#           <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#  1   193.103448    380.00000    -56.66667      29       5      60      85      24      26
#  2   -36.708861    115.55556    -32.35294      79      45      34      50      97      23
#  3    -4.878049    -23.75000     22.44898      41      80      49      39      61      60
#  4   -71.910112    300.00000    -71.87500      89      13      96      25      52      27
#  5   -87.368421    -28.07018     10.20408      95      57      49      12      41      54
#  6   680.000000    323.80952    -12.22222       5      21      90      39      89      79
#  7     9.433962    184.61538    -81.52174      53      13      92      58      37      17
#  8   -75.555556    -61.84211    -32.78689      90      76      61      22      29      41
#  9   -19.642857    -80.00000     14.28571      56      90      42      45      18      48
# 10   -52.173913    -52.63158    480.00000      46      38      15      22      18      87
# # ... with 40 more rows
```

Both may need some tweaking...

Comment: Where does `rename_all` function come from? `dplyr` package?

Comment: @AJMA yes, it's from `dplyr`.